# How to get an HTMLElement's aria attributes with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My team uses `carbon-components-react` which has a `TextInput` component.  It renders the `<input />` with `aria-describedBy="<some_id>"` and, if the field is invalid, adds a `<div id="<some_id>" />`.

I'm trying to write some React tests using `@testing-library/react` to check the value of the div under different conditions.  I could hardcode the ID in my tests, but I hate to hardcode anything that might change in the future, especially by a 3rd party.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the `aria-describedBy` attribute of my input.

```js
test('has the right error message', () => {
  const wrapper = render(<MyComponent />);
  const input = wrapper.findByLabelText('My required field');
  fireEvent.click(input);
  fireEvent.blur(input);

  const error = document.getElementById(input['aria-describedBy']); // input['aria-describedBy'] is undefined
  expect(error.innerText).toBe('This field is required, scrub.');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stack Overflow often does, it provided a fantastic rubber duck, so I figured I'd finish the question and write up the answer.

Use `input.getAttribute('aria-describedBy')`.